# What is the French word for linguistic "borrowing" or "loanword" that came from English? 

Tags: traduction, anglais, emprunts

In English we call a word originally from a foreign language a "borrowing" or "loanword". What is/are the French term(s) for words that came into French from another language?

Also, is there a word specific for words which came into French from English, such as "Anglicism"?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) is usually a good way of translating technical terms. [Borrowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borrowing) (en) → [Loanword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) (en) → [emprunt lexical](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emprunt_lexical) (fr).

Comment: *anglicisme*!!! (just kidding) Maybe "mot d'emprunt"?

Comment: The question title has been dumbed down and is no longer what I asked. I primarily wanted to know the French term for borrowing or loanword to use in question tags here. I wanted to know if there was a further more specific word for borrowings from English as a side question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One would say *emprunter* et *emprunt* for *to borrow* and *borrowing* / *loanword*. And *anglicisme* is the carbon-copy of *anglicism*.

Comment: Am I correct to assume *emprunt* is the noun for either and *emprunter* is the verb *to borrow*?

Comment: @hippietrail You are, I'll edit my answer to make it more obvious.

Comment: And that's what the TLF says too, see for example the entry for _sandwich_: http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/sandwich where it says "Empr. à l'angl. _sandwich_" ("**Emprunté** à l'anglais _sandwich_")

Comment: Un emprunt, moi aussi je suis tout à fait d'accord @hippietrail.